# Is there a sensible way to import a csv to postgres where one column has multiple values per row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I'm new to relational databases and unsure what to do in the following scenario. I have 2 tables, one of which has an id primary key that is also referenced in the other.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int,
  x int,
  y int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  t1_id int,
  id int,
  w int,
  z int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
);
```

For both of these tables I am importing data with `\copy`, for example:

`\copy table1 from 'data/table1.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`

The issue is that whereas the `id` column in the csv that populates table1 has all ints, some of the values in the `t1_id` column of table2's csv are multiple ids separated by semicolon e.g. `1062;1553`.

I'm not sure what the best approach to represent this kind of data in a Postgresql database is. Should I create a third intermediate table of some kind? I need to account for the fact that the foreign key in table2's data refers to the unique primary key from table1, but that there might be more than one (or zero) per row.

Comment: What is the meaning of the semicolon-separated values?  Is each value logically associated with all the other values in the row?  Or, should each of these values have its own separate column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no they are not associated with eachother, they are two separate ids referring to different table1 rows

Comment: Edit your question, add sample data, and then explain how that data should be represented in your Postgres table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is that I'm not sure how the data should be represented, that is part of the question. How can I represent the many:1 relationship of t1_id in table2 and id in table1?

Comment: If you can't paste in your original CSV data, then we can't help you.

Comment: At first glance it seems you concentrating on the wrong issue. **How is this data used after it's been loaded?** Since you indicate that each value in the csv column refers to  an id in table1 it would seem each value needs to become a row in your table2.  You need a staging table to load the csv and a function to parse into separate values and insert each into table2.

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise this is efficient, but you could turn the t1_id column into an array of integers instead of an integer and then invoke a trigger function to check values before inserting.

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  t1_id int[],
  id int,
  w int,
  z int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table2_insert_trigger()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  included_items int[];
BEGIN
  select array_agg (id)
  into included_items
  from table1
  where id = any (NEW.t1_id);

  if cardinality (NEW.t1_id) = cardinality (included_items) then
    return NEW;
  else
    raise exception 'Id(s) not found in table1';
  end if;
END;
$function$;

create trigger insert_table2_trigger before insert
on table2 for each row execute procedure table2_insert_trigger();
```

If table1 contains id 1, 2, 3 and 4, this would work:

```
insert into table2 values (array[1,2], 1, 2, 3);
```

And this would fail:

```
insert into table2 values (array[1,5], 1, 2, 3);
```

> SQL Error [P0001]: ERROR: Id(s) not found in table1   Where: PL/pgSQL
>   function table2_insert_trigger() line 13 at RAISE

Again, I can't swear to efficiency, but try it and see if it works.